# Laravel passport logs users out after deployment

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Everytime we use CD for production deployment of our Laravel application authenticated with Passport package, logged in user are being logged out.
We use passport for API auth purposes.
Any solution how we can stop users from being logged out?

Specs:

> Laravel version: 7
> Passport version: 9
> Session driver: file & redis tested (although passport doesn't use it)

Comment: what session driver you are using

Comment: @MoussabKbeisy file

Comment: are you sure that the file is  save after the CD process ?

Comment: try to use database session driver instead

Comment: That's a possibility, i'll check it.

Comment: @MoussabKbeisy It didn't work, i used Redis.

Comment: well Redis is not a good option if it restarts when CD runs. you could use file and after that copy your storage/framework/sessions some where else before CD process starts and after CD process end replace that folder with new onle.

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh What i don't understand is that Passport is a token base OAuth package so it shouldn't use session. but i'm gonna test DB driver for sessions.